# Error initializing SparkContext., Containers logs: ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL 1 5: SIGTERM End of LogType:stderr

Tags: apache-spark

When I start the spark-yarn using this command "`spark-shell --master yarn-client`" Im getting an error saying:

```
ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The full error I got in starting spark shell with yarn is below, the logs about yarn containers is here:

```
Container: container_1463670715317_0002_01_000001 on masternode_52694
============================================================================
LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time:Thu May 19 16:19:54 +0100 2016
LogLength:5748
Log Contents:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/hadoop-hadoopadmin/nm-local-dir/usercache /hadoopadmin/filecache/13/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/S taticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/li b/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/05/19 16:19:44 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Registered signal handlers for [T ERM, HUP, INT]
16/05/19 16:19:45 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: ApplicationAttemptId: appattempt_ 1463670715317_0002_000001
16/05/19 16:19:46 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoopadmin
16/05/19 16:19:46 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoopadm in
16/05/19 16:19:46 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication di sabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hadoopadmin); users w ith modify permissions: Set(hadoopadmin)
16/05/19 16:19:46 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for Spark driver to be re achable.
16/05/19 16:19:46 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Driver now available: 10.17.0.50: 43771
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Add WebUI Filter. AddW ebUIFilter(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter,Map(PROXY_ HOSTS -> masternode, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://masternode:8088/proxy/a pplication_1463670715317_0002),/proxy/application_1463670715317_0002)
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0 :8030
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.YarnRMClient: Registering the ApplicationMaster
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Will request 2 executor containers, e ach with 1 cores and 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container request (host: Any, capabil ity: <memory:1408, vCores:1>)
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container request (host: Any, capabil ity: <memory:1408, vCores:1>)
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Started progress reporter thread with (heartbeat : 3000, initial allocation : 200) intervals
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : masternode:52694
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Launching container container_1463670 715317_0002_01_000002 for on host masternode
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Launching ExecutorRunnable. driverUrl : spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.17.0.50:43771, executorHostname: masternode
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Starting Executor Container
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Received 1 containers from YARN, laun ching executors on 1 of them.
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: yarn.client.max-ca ched-nodemanagers-proxies : 0
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Setting up ContainerLaunchContext
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Preparing Local resources
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Prepared Local resources Map(_spa rk_.jar -> resource
{ scheme: "hdfs" host: "localhost" port: 9000 file: "/user/ hadoopadmin/.sparkStaging/application_1463670715317_0002/spark-assembly-1.6.1-ha doop2.6.0.jar" }
size: 187698038 timestamp: 1463671182405 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE)
16/05/19 16:19:48 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable:
===============================================================================
YARN executor launch context:
env:
CLASSPATH -> PWD<CPS>PWD/_spark_.jar<CPS>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR<CPS>$HAD OOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/commo n/lib/<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/ha doop/hdfs/lib/<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/ share/hadoop/yarn/lib/<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/<CPS>$HA DOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/
SPARK_LOG_URL_STDERR -> http://masternode:8042/node/containerlogs/conta iner_1463670715317_0002_01_000002/hadoopadmin/stderr?start=-4096
SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR -> .sparkStaging/application_1463670715317_0002
SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_FILE_SIZES -> 187698038
SPARK_USER -> hadoopadmin
SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_VISIBILITIES -> PRIVATE
SPARK_YARN_MODE -> true
SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_TIME_STAMPS -> 1463671182405
SPARK_LOG_URL_STDOUT -> http://masternode:8042/node/containerlogs/conta iner_1463670715317_0002_01_000002/hadoopadmin/stdout?start=-4096
SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES -> hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoopadmin/.sparkStagi ng/application_1463670715317_0002/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar#_spark_ .jar
command:
JAVA_HOME/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' -Xms1024m -X mx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir=PWD/tmp '-Dspark.driver.port=43771' -Dspark.yarn.ap p.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBac kend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.17.0.50:43771 --executor-id 1 --hostname masternode --cores 1 --app-id application_1463670715317_0002 - -user-class-path file:$PWD/__app__.jar 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr
===============================================================================
16/05/19 16:19:48 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : masternode:52694
16/05/19 16:19:48 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
16/05/19 16:19:48 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: UNDEFINED, exit Code: 0, (reason: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.)
16/05/19 16:19:48 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
End of LogType:stderr
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Thu May 19 16:19:54 +0100 2016
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
End of LogType:stdout
Container: container_1463670715317_0002_02_000002 on masternode_52694
============================================================================
LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time:Thu May 19 16:19:54 +0100 2016
LogLength:737
Log Contents:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/hadoop-hadoopadmin/nm-local-dir/usercache /hadoopadmin/filecache/13/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/S taticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/li b/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/05/19 16:19:54 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL 1 5: SIGTERM
End of LogType:stderr
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Thu May 19 16:19:54 +0100 2016
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
End of LogType:stdout
hadoopadmin@master:~$
```

The full error that it shows when I try to start spark with "`spark-shell --master yarn-client`":

```
hadoopadmin@master:~$ spark-shell --master yarn-client
16/05/19 16:19:33 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/05/19 16:19:33 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoopadmin
16/05/19 16:19:33 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoopadmin
16/05/19 16:19:33 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hadoopadmin); users with modify permissions: Set(hadoopadmin)
16/05/19 16:19:33 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/05/19 16:19:33 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/05/19 16:19:33 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:37052
16/05/19 16:19:33 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP class server' on port 37052.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_77)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
16/05/19 16:19:37 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
16/05/19 16:19:37 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoopadmin
16/05/19 16:19:37 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoopadmin
16/05/19 16:19:37 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hadoopadmin); users with modify permissions: Set(hadoopadmin)
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 43771.
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.17.0.50:57722]
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 57722.
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-e8de3854-2526-4725-8c73-edb3fce2df33
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/05/19 16:19:38 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.17.0.50:4040
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
16/05/19 16:19:39 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
16/05/19 16:19:40 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar -> hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoopadmin/.sparkStaging/application_1463670715317_0002/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar
16/05/19 16:19:42 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-942afe6a-95ca-4b8b-b06f-e9e3ac6aa751/__spark_conf__5009784131719458516.zip -> hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoopadmin/.sparkStaging/application_1463670715317_0002/__spark_conf__5009784131719458516.zip
16/05/19 16:19:42 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoopadmin
16/05/19 16:19:42 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoopadmin
16/05/19 16:19:42 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hadoopadmin); users with modify permissions: Set(hadoopadmin)
16/05/19 16:19:42 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application 2 to ResourceManager
16/05/19 16:19:42 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1463670715317_0002
16/05/19 16:19:43 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1463670715317_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/05/19 16:19:43 INFO yarn.Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: N/A
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: default
         start time: 1463671182634
         final status: UNDEFINED
         tracking URL: http://masternode:8088/proxy/application_1463670715317_0002/
         user: hadoopadmin
16/05/19 16:19:44 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1463670715317_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/05/19 16:19:45 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1463670715317_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/05/19 16:19:46 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1463670715317_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null)
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> masternode, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://masternode:8088/proxy/application_1463670715317_0002), /proxy/application_1463670715317_0002
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO ui.JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1463670715317_0002 (state: RUNNING)
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO yarn.Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: N/A
         ApplicationMaster host: 10.17.0.50
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
         queue: default
         start time: 1463671182634
         final status: UNDEFINED
         tracking URL: http://masternode:8088/proxy/application_1463670715317_0002/
         user: hadoopadmin
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1463670715317_0002 has started running.
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 49183.
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 49183
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.17.0.50:49183 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.17.0.50, 49183)
16/05/19 16:19:47 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/05/19 16:19:51 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null)
16/05/19 16:19:51 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> masternode, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://masternode:8088/proxy/application_1463670715317_0002), /proxy/application_1463670715317_0002
16/05/19 16:19:51 INFO ui.JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/05/19 16:19:54 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn application has already exited with state FINISHED!
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.17.0.50:4040
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/05/19 16:19:54 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
16/05/19 16:20:09 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms)
16/05/19 16:20:09 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:584)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:26)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:30)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
16/05/19 16:20:09 INFO spark.SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:584)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at <init>(<console>:26)
        at .<init>(<console>:30)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at ... org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.implicits._
                ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.sql
                ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Something exceeded it's memory budget. No helpful errors but that's what it was for me. Try upping various parameters like `MaxPermSize` and `memoryOverhead`.

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201507.mbox/%3c55A372C5.9050801@googlemail.com%3e

Comment: How do you see this is an issue with Memory ? I dont find any way to see the real consumed memory.

Comment: Confused... Why do you say memory is the issue. It clearly says `error: not found: value sqlContext`

Comment: Things move very quickly in Spark. This answer reflects my experience with Spark 1.5.x/1.6.x. Spark is now at 2.2.0 and things have changed significantly.